# Is it possible to find peaks in a csv file and add the peaks in a separate column in the same csv file? (without plotting)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scipy

This is a piece of my code, but I don't know how to get this array as new column Height to the original csv file in the format?

| Date | Level | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 45 | 0 |
| 02-01-2021 | 43 | 0 |
| 03-01-2021 | 47 | 1 |
| 04-01-2021 | 46 | 0 |
| ..... |  |  |

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bestand = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=1, usecols=[0, 1] , names=['date', 'level'])
bestand = bestand['level']

indices = find_peaks(bestand, height= 37, threshold=None, distance=None)

height  = indices[1]['peak_heights']
print(height)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to assign a column named `height` that takes the value 1 when `level` is a peak according to `find_peaks()`. If so:

```py
# Declare column full of zeros
bestand['height'] = 0
# Get row number of observations that are peaks
idx = find_peaks(x=bestand['level'], height=37)[0]
# Select rows in `idx` and replace their `height` with 1
bestand.iloc[idx, 2] = 1
```

Which returns this:

```
         date  level  height
0  01-01-2021     45       0
1  02-01-2021     43       0
2  03-01-2021     47       1
3  04-01-2021     46       0
```

Comment: Hello Arturo, thanks for the reply. This is exactly what I want to do, but should the last row: bestand.iloc[idx, 2] = 1 or what do you mean with peaks?

Comment: Oh, that's true. I fixed the issue. You are right, the last row should have been `bestand.iloc[idx, 2] = 1`. I edited the answer to fix this!

Comment: Hi Arturo, thanks, that is working excellent! Nice...

Comment: Glad to help! Remember you can vote and accept answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure I understood your question.

You just want to save the results?

```
bastand['Heigth'] = indices
bastand.to_csv('file.csv')
```